# Data aggregation based on differently written names in R

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

In R I have data

```
Name   number
Peter   14
peter   2
hans    11
...
```

My question is how do I find the names with Big letter and combine them small letter. For example I want to combine `peter` and `Peter` and the the sum of the `number` which in this case is 14+2=16.

Say I have over 500 names where some start with small letter and some start with Big letter - how should I solve this in general?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `aggregate()` in combination with `tolower()`. Thus all names are converted to small characters only. The aggregation is then applied with `sum`. This can be stored to a new object, let's say `dfAgg`

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("Peter", "peter", "Hans", "hans"), number = c(14,2,11,3))

dfAgg <- aggregate(number ~ tolower(name), data = df, sum)
dfAgg
# tolower(name) number
#          hans     14
#         peter     16
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, You can ignore the case sensitivity. Make all the names to upper or lower and then count the quantity.
Ex:

- toupper("peter")
- toupper("Peter")

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
names_nums <- read.table(text="Name   number
Peter   14
peter   2
hans    11", header=T)

sum(names_nums[tolower(names_nums$Name) == "peter",]$number)
```

You can get the sum for all of them as follows:

```
do.call(rbind,lapply(split(names_nums, tolower(names_nums$Name)), function(x) {
    sum(x$number)
}))
```

Thanks!